# #Python string slicing and change the order of a string

Tags: python

How should I change the order of a string?

```
a = 'abcdefg'
```

and I want to put the last character of the string at beginning every time when I iterate through the string

```
a = 'gabcdef'
a = 'fgabcde`
etc
```

Comment: Updated: `a=a[-1]+a[:-1]`

Comment: @PrateekDewan, this will give the wrong output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
a = a[-1] + a[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like a = a[-1] + a[:-1]

```
a = 'abcdefg'
for i in range(len(a)):
    a = a[-1] + a[:-1]
    print(a)

>>gabcdef
>>fgabcde
>>efgabcd    
>>defgabc
>>cdefgab    
>>bcdefga
>>abcdefg
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `deque` as an alternative to slicing:

```
from collections import deque
a = 'abcdefg'
d = deque(a)

for _ in range(len(a)):
    d.rotate()
    print(''.join(d))
```

Output:

```
gabcdef
fgabcde
efgabcd
defgabc
cdefgab
bcdefga
abcdefg
```